# Minimize xibs variety for localizations and iPhone 4/5

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, interface-builder, xib

As I know from official sources, when we localize `xib` files we need to duplicate them and replace translated strings in Interface Builder.

And to support iPhone's 4" screen we need to make separate version of `xib` with height of 586 pixels (I had problems with autoresized top-level views without corresponding view controllers in common `xib`). In this case it's almost impossible to tune up interface in future updates.

How to minimize this variety (perfectly to single `xib` file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use an extra xib for every language, set the labels etc. in code (and use a Localizable.strings file)
2. Learn how to use layout constraints in your xib to support 3,5" and 4" displays

That's how I do it, and it works

Comment: Thanks. Setting labels in code require some extra work (to link IBOutlets) and grows up the code. As for layout feature, I can't use it because I must support iOS 5. I'm still looking for some elegant (maybe through external tool) solution.

Comment: The auto-resizing functions in IB can also be used to support both screens and it works with iOS 5. However, if you find a nice tool, please post it ;)

Comment: I concur, auto-resizing is not a problem with earlier iOS versions.

Comment: Looks like truth. I met a problem with top-level views, but here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997967/problem-setting-autosizing-in-interface-builder is a solution.